RX gate in series
I have to apply two Rx gates in series. How do I do it?
    from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

    import numpy as np

    q = QuantumRegister(1,'q')
    
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(q,c)

    A=circuit.rx(np.pi/2,q[0])
    circuit.rx(np.pi/2,A)
    circuit.measure(q,c)

    print(circuit)


You already have it in your code. Please elaborate more what you think is wrong. Does your circuit behaves differently than expected?

There is no need to make the following assignment: A=circuit.rx(np.pi/2,q[0]) and then pass A as an argument to the next rx application.
You simply run the QuantumCircuit.rx() method twice with the corresponding angles you want to apply:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit

q = QuantumRegister(1,'q')
c = ClassicalRegister(1,'c')
    
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q,c)

circuit.rx(np.pi/2,q[0])
circuit.rx(np.pi/2,q[0])
circuit.measure(q,c)

print(circuit)

